# How to know whether VBA runtime environment is stopped or running?

Tags: events, vba, runtime

In my VBA code, I get a runtime exception (say divide by zero) and after pressing 'End' in the error box, the VBA runtime gets stopped.

During this stop, my global Objects are getting cleared. I want these objects to retain their values. Because, when I start over again, since these objects are `Nothing`, I am having issues.

Is there any event in VBA which will get triggered when my runtime gets stopped?? Or is there any way to know whether VBA is still running or stopped?

Comment: If your code isn't running, then VBA has stopped. :-)

Comment: :) Thats true. I need to know it programmatically... Want to know whether any event will get triggered while the execution stops.. Or will there be any flag available to decide whether vba is runnin or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, an unhandled exception clears global variables.  So add error handlers to your VBA procedures.

Here is a transcript of a session in the Immediate window, using the 2 procedures included below.

```
MyGlobal = "foo"
Call DemoDivideByZero
? Chr(39) & MyGlobal & Chr(39)
''

MyGlobal = "foo"
Call DemoDivideByZero2
Error 11 (Division by zero) in procedure DemoDivideByZero2
? Chr(39) & MyGlobal & Chr(39)
'foo'
```

A procedure without an error handler ...

```
Public Sub DemoDivideByZero()
    Debug.Print 2 / 0
End Sub
```

A version with an error handler ...

```
Public Sub DemoDivideByZero2()

    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Debug.Print 2 / 0

ExitHere:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
        & ") in procedure DemoDivideByZero2"
    Debug.Print strMsg
    GoTo ExitHere
End Sub
```

However I'm unsure whether including error handlers in your procedures will be enough to preserve your global variable values.  I avoid using globals.

Answer (score 0):

Which global objects do you have? At startup you need to initialise them.

Comment: My objects are initialized from a C# component during start up. Now when execution gets interrupted due to any runtime error, I need to intimate the C# component again to reset my objects. That's why I'm looking for some hook on my VBA end to know when the execution actually stops, so that the c# component gets automatically called during such a Stop in execution.

Comment: Surely you can test for the global object(s)'s initialisation by comparison to Nothing? (use the "is" or "is not" operator).